# Regular expression to allow alphanumeric, only one space and then alpahnumeric

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I've searched and searched and tried many different ways, but I can't seem to figure this out. I'm looking for a way to only allow alphanumeric characters, then only one space, then alphanumeric characters. I'm sure it's easy, but I don't know it.

Examples of what I want:

```
    First Last     Allowed
    First La-st    Not Allowed
    FirstLast      Not Allowed
    First  Last    Not Allowed
    First La'st    Not allowed
```

I'd then like to remove the invalid characters from the string.

Please let me know if you need more information. Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you define alpha-numeric?

Comment: What's the invalid character to remove in "FirstLast"? All characters that are there are valid.

Comment: If you are okay with including underscores, use \w to indicate: a-zA-Z0-9_

Comment: @minitech That's why the string is invalid. The characters are valid. I was commenting on "I'd then like to remove the invalid characters from the string" from the question.

Comment: What about letters and digits outside of ASCII?

Comment: @hvd  The invalid part in "FirstLast" is that there is no space. I need it to have alphanumeric (meaning only capital or lowercase letters and numbers) then only 1 space, then alphanumeric characters.
The regex that minitech posted works to validate, but how do I then remove the invalid characters?

Comment: @user1489735 Again, there are no invalid characters to remove in "FirstLast". The string is invalid, because it has no space, but removing characters cannot make it valid. First make sure what you want to do, then you can decide on how to do it. Could you edit your question to include a list of replacement strings you're looking for? Perhaps `First La-st -> First Last` / `First Last (two spaces) -> First Last (one space)` / `First Second Third -> First SecondThird` / `FirstLast -> FirstLast ` ? (Edit: can't seem to get two spaces to show up correctly.)

Comment: The answers you got seem good, but coming from someone with a hyphenated last name: please, *please* don't use this to validate names.  See ["Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names"](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).  And if you weren't planning to, then I instead address this to anybody else who reads this question next: names can have hyphens, apostrophes, and all sorts of things.

Comment: I'm actually not using this to validate names, it was just a good example.

@hvd Yes, those are exactly the replacement strings that I'm looking for. The only difference is that in the case of "FirstLast", I'd like to actually not accept that value, but I can do that on my own by determining if there is a space at all and if not, then don't accept it.

Comment: @AntalS-Z I didn't read the question that way, but my name wouldn't match either, so thanks for bringing it up :) @user1489735 All the answers so far validate strings, they do not correct them. But you don't actually need to validate that strings don't contain e.g. hyphens if you've already removed all hyphens. You could first replace `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]` (from minitech's comment), and then you don't need to check for any other characters anymore, because if they were there, they're gone. After that, you can split on spaces, verify that you have exactly two (non-empty?) results, and else fix it.

Comment: @user1489735 But admittedly that's a different approach that doesn't answer the question as asked :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+ [a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

… should do it.

Comment: He didn't specify, but I'd assume `^` and `$` would be appropriate here.

Comment: Might well be what the OP wants. But it certainly rejects plenty of alpha-numeric characters.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: Updated it exactly 5 seconds after answering :P

Comment: @CodeInChaos: I guess. We'll see :)

Comment: @minitech I only want letters and numbers. So, this regex worked, but how do I then remove the invalid characters? I've done RegEx.Replace before, but that was if I had a list of characters that weren't allowed, not a list that are allowed.  Thanks!

Comment: @user1489735: Just replace this: `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]` with nothing.

Comment: @minitech The replacing seems to work with everything except if they put in more than one space between the two words.

Comment: @user1489735: Sorry; replace this: `[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]| (?= )` with nothing. [Here's a demo, too.](http://ideone.com/C9iIb)

Comment: @minitech That works great. Only one other thing that I'd like to be able to check for. I only want it to have 2 words. The way it is not, it will allow First Middle Last. I'd like that to be changed to First MiddleLast.  Thanks a lot for all your help!!

Comment: @user1489735: `Split` it by space, `Skip` the first item, and join the remainder together.

Answer (score 6):

This should do it:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]+ [0-9a-zA-Z]+$
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/5m6RH/

Comment: Disagree with the `\s`. I think it should be a space (" ")

Answer (score 5):

Use this regex:

```
^[\p{L}\d]+ [\p{L}\d]+$
```

Comment: Oh right, it's C#. +1. You may want to change that to a space, though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you don't want numbers in names and you are looking for this regex:

```
^\p{L}+ \p{L}+$
```

or

```
^\p{L}+\s\p{L}+$
```

where `\p{L}+` matches one or more "letter" characters, so not just `a-z` and `A-Z`, but also other languages' characters. For example, *Élise Wilson*.

---

If you really want just alphanumeric characters and input should have two sections with one space between; and invalid characters has to be removed, then:

1. replace all matches of `[^\s\dA-Za-z]+` with an empty string,
2. trim leading spaces by replacing `^\s*` with an empty string,
3. trim trailing spaces by replacing `\s*$` with an empty string, and
4. check/validate such string with regex `^[\da-zA-Z]+ [\da-zA-Z]+$`

To exclude numbers from string remove `\d` from above patterns.

To allow longer space between, not just one space character, add `+` behind space character in first pattern or behind `\s` in the second one.

Comment: The replacing seems to work with everything except if they put in more than one space between the two words.

Comment: @user1489735 - then go with `^\p{L}+ +\p{L}+$` or `^\p{L}+\s+\p{L}+$`

Comment: I'm actually not using that regex because I do only want letters and numbers, so I'm using @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+ [a-zA-Z0-9]+$" Then, using the replace in your suggestion in step 1 of your post above. That works for everything but the user putting in more than one space between the words.

Comment: @user1489735 - then `^[\da-zA-Z]+ +[\da-zA-Z]+$` in step 4.

Comment: That actually results in an empty string if I put in something like this: Test  Stuff  (2 spaces between the words). Here is my line of code:  String newFieldValue = Regex.Replace(fieldText, @"^[\da-zA-Z]+ +[\da-zA-Z]+$", "")

Comment: @user1489735 - try `(?<![\da-zA-Z])[\da-zA-Z]+\s+[\da-zA-Z]+(?![\da-zA-Z])$` then

Answer (score 0):

**This should work**

```
(?i)\b[a-z\d]+ [a-z\d]+\b
```

Answer (score 0):

this will work perfectly for alphanumeric and only one space between them if applicable

```
    @"^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([ ]{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$"
```

it will allow like values

```
    anand
    anand dev
    anand123 
    anand123 dev
    123anand
    123anand dev123
    my user name is anand123
    anand123  dev               **Not allowed due to multiple space**
     anand dev                  **not allowed due to space at begining**
```

Hope this will help you.
Thanks.

Comment: The OP seems to have wanted exactly 2 words with exactly 1 space between them, not "one or more" words with single spaces in between, like your solution.